# MIPS efficient using shifts

Tags: assembly, mips

I have one homework assignment that I have to code a function in MIPS Assembly and that function must use shifts and must be the most efficient possible.

The assembly code is called on C by `func(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5);`

This is my code and it is working as expected.

```
01          .data
02          .text
03          .globl  func
04
05  func:
06      
07      lw      $8, 16($29)     
08      addi    $29,$29, -20        
09      sw      $31,0($29)      
10      
11      # f = 16x1 + 8x2 + 4x3 + 2x4 + x5 This is what the function do
12      
13      
14      li      $9,0        
15      li      $10,0       
16      li      $11,16  
17
18              # Load the five function parameter on function
19      sb      $4,4($29)
20      sb      $5,8($29)
21      sb      $6,12($29)
22      sb      $7,16($29)
23      sb      $8,20($29)
24
25      la      $25,4($29)
26  loop:
27      
28      lb      $24,0($25)
29      mul     $12,$11,$24     
30      add     $9,$9,$12       
31      
32      srl     $11,$11,1       
33      addi    $25,$25,4
34      #addi   $29,$29,1
35      
36      addi    $10,$10,1       
37      ble     $10,4,loop      
38
39      
40      move    $2,$9           
41  end:    
42      
43      lw      $31,0($29)
44      addi    $29,$29,20      
45      jr      $31
```

So what I'm asking is that this code can be done most efficient using shifts?

I have made a `srl` to access the value to multiply by but in don't know if using shifts I can access the 5 parameter of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Even though the code is working, you're not actually allocating enough space on the stack. You're allocating 20 bytes but you're accessing the 21st byte with `sb $8,20($29)`.
- You don't have to index registers by 0: the offset is implicitly 0 if you just do `sw $31,($29)`.
- I don't know what the conventions are in your class, but I'd suggest using the aliases for important registers, such as `$ra` instead of `$31`, `$sp` instead of `$29`, etc. I find it more readable.
- Lastly, the multiplication! Here's a hint:

  `x << y` is the same as `x * (2^y)`. So `x << 4` is `x * 16`, `x << 3` is `x * 8`, etc.

  Are your coefficients in the main equation all powers of 2? Yup. Here's what I suggest: start your loop counter at 4 and count down to 0. This way you can use the loop counter as the shift value, and it eliminates the need for using $11.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanations. My Math backgroud is not the best so this little things get triky to me :)